# not able to run chkdsk on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, chkdsk

I'm trying to run chkdsk from the command line and am receiving the following error message "Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges. You have to invoke this utility running in an elevated mode." The account has administrative rights. Do I need to be logged in as admin?

Comment: Launch an elevated command prompt and then run chkdsk.

Comment: Next time first [google](https://www.google.nl/#q=does+chkdsk+require+admin) :)

Comment: @shub It indeed belonged at the question and not in the answer :).

Answer (score 10):

You need to have an account that is an admin on your computer **and** run *cmd* As An Administrator:

[image]

Then you will be shown with a UAC dialog, if you are logged in as an Admin, click yes.

If not, then type in an Admin's username and, if the Admin has one (which it should ;)), their password.

Now use `chkdsk`

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://ask-leo.com/chkdsk_what_is_it_and_how_do_i_run_it.html) you need to run cmd as administrator in order to execute it.

> Our first problem: CHKDSK requires that you not only be administrator, but that you run the program as administrator. The two are not the same...

The [link](http://ask-leo.com/chkdsk_what_is_it_and_how_do_i_run_it.html) explains it all.

Comment: If you remove the "next time google" comment I will upvote your answer.

Comment: The site clearly states one should search on the web first. ´
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?´ states the how to ask. So, I will not remove my comment.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comment its just not friendly.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand your point, I see Shub changed it already. It was never harsh intended.

Comment: Don't get me wrong.  Your answer is good, you quote and link to the source, but the comment could have been done in a comment.  **Answers are for everyone.**

Comment: I did look around on the site first, but yeah I guess googling would have helped. I did not realize it was such an easy question and thought it indicated a problem.

Answer (score 2):

A less common reason that you can see this error is if Windows is having trouble accessing the particular drive that you're attempting to check.

It will still provide the same error message suggesting that you need administrative privileges regardless of being logged in with Admin rights at an administrative command line.

Sometimes as simple as unplugging and reconnecting an external disk.